# how to upload a javascript generated output to a databse, using mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there is a way to upload or update the generated output of this javascript program to a MySQL database with PHP.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function randomString() {

  var totalIterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = '';

  var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var stringLength = 5;

  for (var iterations = 0; iterations < totalIterations; iterations++) {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    // generating the randomString by calling another function : 
    item.innerHTML = generateRandomString(stringLength, chars);
     output.appendChild(item);
  }
}

function generateRandomString(length, chars) {
    var randomstring = '';
    // generating the random string
    for (var i = 0; i <  length ; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring = randomstring + chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }

    return randomstring;
}
</script>

<form name="randform">
<input type="button"  value="Create Random String" 
onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;</input>
<input type="text" id="input" name="randomfield" value="">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is of course! But your code is kind of "naked" . To write to a db with just vanilla js and php in the php code you need to connect to your db and send it data that it gets from js as a global var, then write that to your table. In what you have here. From the Front-end you need to send a `GET` or `POST` request to the php file with the data you want to send. Imho it'd be easiest to do that in your `randomString()` function. Just add a variable that holds the string and send it to the php.

Comment: Yes. I think you are looking for AJAX. Do a google on it and try a few tutorials.

Comment: ok. so i should just add a post method to the form and then create a variable that holds the out put and then send it to php so that i could upload it to the mysql database from there right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly can't javascript work?

Comment: YES! AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML

Comment: I think in your case it would be easier to just convert your javascript functions to PHP functions.

Comment: Yes, You can use AJAX call to  a php page( sending the js data) on your server, In that php page write the code for insertion.

Comment: okey. @GrumpyCrouton i think so too, but i will have to change some things and i wouldn't want to do that

Comment: There is also the option to send your form to a php script, with your wanted value as an input (hidden or not). If you don't want to do that, then AJAX is your solution.